# Can't see a new window after running SFML graphics

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml, clion

I trying to test out SFML with Clion following [this](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2015/06/02/Creating-an-SFML-project-on-Mac-OS-using-CLion-and-CMake.aspx) tutorial. I got to the last part with the SFML example. It compiles with no errors, it sees the SFML, but when I run the actual program all I get is:

```
C:\Users\yurys\CLionProjects\SFMLDemo\cmake-build-debug\SFMLDemo.exe

Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

According to the tutorial I'm suppose to see a [new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njASD.png).

I use MinGW32 with gcc 5.3.0 so my installed version of SFML matches it. I have another version installed to use with Visual Studio 2017.

My CMake files is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(SFMLDemo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(SFMLDemo ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
link_directories("C:/Clion_SFML/") #Path to the SFML Libraries
if (SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(SFMLDemo ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

---

Code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640,480,32),"Hello SFML");

    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("OpenSans-Bold.ttf");

    sf::Text text("Hello World",font,11);
    text.setCharacterSize(32);
    text.setPosition(window.getSize().x/2 - text.getGlobalBounds().width/2,
                     window.getSize().y/2 - text.getGlobalBounds().height/2);


    while(window.isOpen()){

        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
                window.close();
            }

            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            window.draw(text);
            window.display();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the SFML .dll's in the executable's directory?

Comment: @Bumrang No, all the SFML Libraries are on my C:\ drive.

Comment: @Bumrang Thanks that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments but I'll submit it as an answer so that it's more visible to others:

In this case, SFML is being linked dynamically. Make sure that the proper .DLLs that are required for SFML are in the same directory as the executable.